# Need help using pyinstaller to make standalone application

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hi does anyone know how to use cx_freeze?

I'm running debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)

I've got 4 .py files.

Im using python3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Refer PyInstaller [Manual](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html).

Or you may use [Freeze](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze).

Comment: pyinstaller does not work for python3. Do you have any idea how to use cx_freeze?

Comment: Cx freeze id very simple. Google for its deb file. Install it. Then open the terminal and type cxfreeze py_filepath.

Comment: Does it matter which python i install cx_freeze with?